# I found myself in Grub Rescue after deleting a partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, grubrescue

**That's how I caused the disaster in the first place:**
**--------------------------------------------------------------------**

I logged to my other distro (I have three on two drives) Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, updated it, but it acted kinda funny and there was like buzzing coming from inside, very faint, I could barely hear it. Anyway, at some point I ran:

```
$ ps -aux | grep paul
```

...to see what was going on and I saw there was over 700k active processes, a moment later 10k more. I decided to remove the distro altogether and to try a different one. I rebooted back to my Ubuntu GamePack and removed 20.04 using program called disks.
I remember that a message followed, saying that I should reboot now, because kernel does not yet know about what happened. I did and immediately began installation of elementaryOS in its place.

At the very end of the process a red message popped up, saying that a fatal error occured and the installation couldn't be completed and, none of the options available to me at that time worked. I could only reboot. 
In short, moments later in Grub Rescue I first did the "ls" thing. Every guide starts from it, they're all one google away and so I'll just say, none of this guides completely worked for me. I always ended up with an error. And then I found this solution on some website:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from live media, then do:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
$ sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
$ sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
$ sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
 
$ sudo chroot /mnt
 
$ grub-install /dev/sda
$ grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
$ update-grub

$ exit && sudo umount /mnt/dev && sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts && sudo umount /mnt/proc && sudo umount /mnt/sys && sudo umount /mnt
```

Reboot